# Absolute Positioning Trouble

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying write some CSS for my site so that it will display well with jQuery mobile but I'm having some trouble repositioning some elements.

In my normal site the logo appears before the `<h1>` element. However, in the mobile site I've set my `<h1>` to appear as the header with the logo just below it through absolute positioning. This works just fine until you come to a page with a longer `<h1>` that drops onto a second line on a mobile screen. This expands the header `div` but doesn't push the logo `div` down. Maybe I'm going about this all wrong but I'm not really sure how to fix this.

Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/fvJQL/

HTML:

```
<div id="logo">
<img id="logo-img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Littlebluedog.svg/120px-Littlebluedog.svg.png" alt="dog">
</div>

<h1 id="header-text">All About Dogs All About DogsAll About DogsAll About DogsAll About DogsAll About DogsAll About Dogs</h1>
```

CSS:

```
#header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the logo below the `<h1>` and positioning it for the normal site and letting it fall below in the mobile?  Then you could remove the `position:absolute:` for mobile and let it fall where it should normally.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute positioning will make the H1 act independently to the other elements.

Just put the text above the image and it will push other elements down if the text goes onto a second line.

Markup

```
<h1 id="header-text">All About Dogs All About All About Dogs All AboutAll About Dogs All AboutAll About Dogs All About</h1>
<div id="logo">
  <img id="logo-img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Littlebluedog.svg/120px-Littlebluedog.svg.png" alt="dog">
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #header-text {
 margin:0;
 display:block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 width: 100%;
}

#logo {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top:0px;
}
```

Hope it saved: http://jsfiddle.net/fvJQL/8/